# Issue with sending html email

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, mime-message, itemwriter

I have created a small spring batch application which will read data from the file and send an html email . The StudentProcessor creates MImeMessage and ItemWriter sends the email
The file contains Student Id and Student Name, Home city, Visiting city
StudentDetails POJO:

```java
public class StudentDetails {

  public String getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getHomeCity() {
    return homeCity;
  }

  public void setHomeCity(String homeCity) {
    this.homeCity = homeCity;
  }

  public String getVisitingCity() {
    return visitingCity;
  }

  public void setVisitingCity(String visitingCity) {
    this.visitingCity = visitingCity;
  }

  private String studentId;
  private String name;
  private String homeCity;
  private String visitingCity;

}
```

My job.xml is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

    <bean id="studentDetails" class="com.ubs.classfiercompositeWriter.StudentDetails" scope="prototype" />

    <import resource = "context.xml" />
    <import resource = "database.xml" />
    <job id="classifiercompositeWriter" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <step id="step1">
            <tasklet>
                <chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" processor="StudentEmailRowMapper" writer="feedStatusItemWriter"
                       commit-interval="1" >

                </chunk>
            </tasklet>
        </step>
    </job>


    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader"
          class="org.beanio.spring.BeanIOFlatFileItemReader"
          scope="step">
        <property name="streamMapping" value="classpath:/record-mapping.xml"></property>
        <property name="streamName" value="dataFile"></property>
        <property name="resource" value="file:C:/ABC/src/main/resources/data/input.csv"></property>
    </bean>





    <bean id="StudentEmailRowMapper" class="com.ubs.classfiercompositeWriter.StudentProcessor"></bean>


    <bean id="feedStatusItemWriter"
          class="org.springframework.batch.item.mail.javamail.MimeMessageItemWriter">
        <property name="javaMailSender" ref="mailSender" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

My common content.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" id="jobRepository">

        <property ref="transactionManager" name="transactionManager"/>

    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" id="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher" id="jobLauncher">
        <property ref="jobRepository" name="jobRepository"/>

    </bean>


    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="mailhost-arec.ch"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

STudent Processor:

```java
public class StudentProcessor implements
  ItemProcessor<StudentDetails, MimeMessagePreparator> {
  @Override
  public MimeMessagePreparator process(StudentDetails student)
    throws Exception {
    MimeMessagePreparator msg = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
      @Override
      public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
        mimeMessage.setFrom("noreply@abc.com");
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,"nik.kard@gma.com");
        mimeMessage.setSubject("Welcome message !!");
        mimeMessage.setText("Hello " + student.getName());
        System.out.println("Hello mime");

        System.out.println(mimeMessage.toString());

      }
    };

    return msg;
  }
}
```

I put an debugger in MimeMessagePreparator prepare function but the code doesn't reach the debugger. It just skips and goes to line "return msg";
Since the msg doesnt get generated. The ItemWriter fails.
I am not sure what is the issue here. Can some one please advise?

Comment: On a side note I would recommend using Lombok for your pojos. Saves you generating all the getters and setters. Just import it in your pom.xml, and use the @Data annotation in your pojo

Answer (score 0):

The breakpoint location you put will only be triggered when it actually sends the email in  `MimeMessageItemWriter` which expects to receive the object in the type of `MimeMessage` from the output of `ItemProcessor` but now you are returning a `MimeMessagePreparator` . So it never be executed as it does not receive the right argument type and hence the breakpoint will never be triggered.

So return the `MimeMessage` from the `ItemProcessor` please :

```java
@Component
public class StudentProcessor implements ItemProcessor<StudentDetails, MimeMessagePreparator> {

  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

  @Override
  public MimeMessagePreparator process(StudentDetails student) throws Exception {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        mimeMessage.setFrom("noreply@abc.com");
        mimeMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,"nik.kard@gma.com");
        mimeMessage.setSubject("Welcome message !!");
        mimeMessage.setText("Hello " + student.getName());
        System.out.println("Hello mime");
        return mimeMessage;
    };
}
```